# How to create a page view of two content type in Drupal 7

Tags: views

I have two content type named as workshop and meetings. I wanted to create a new page view (say events) of these content type such that event page should have titles of post from each content grouped with content type.

I tried to create this view but I can't select multiple content type while creating a view.

Comment: Once you've created the view, you can edit the filters. Edit the filter called 'content type' and you can add several types.

Comment: @GisleHannemyr yep, should have done, was writing from my phone. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it: Once you've created your view, selecting either one of your content types:

1. Under "filter criteria", click the filter called "content type (= YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE).
2. Select "is one of", and then select all the content types you want to include.
3. Click Apply (all displays).
4. Save the view.